# Moodle module type

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

I am tasked with writing a relatively small and simple PHP web app which will use a small database. Authentication for this will be through randomly generated hex keys in the query string which are generated by an administration page and emailed to desired users.

This is all fine so far, but here's the catch:

For various political reasons, we are forced to make this app a Moodle module. I can use the Moodle database in MySQL, but I will be working with my own tables which do not interact with Moodle, and Moodle will not interact with my tables. I must also to use the Moodle database abstraction rather than direct PHP->MySQL access.

I do not want my users to know they are operating within Moodle. They shouldn't need to log in to Moodle to access my web app, and they probably won't have access to Moodle anyway. Those users who do have access to Moodle shouldn't see this web app in their list of Moodle functions.

I've thrown together a few small PHP pages, included some Moodle libs, and placed the code in the moodle/mods directory. Accessing the PHP pages on the server with the URLs directly result in a Moodle error, since I'm not accessing the module through proper channels. I get the "Incorrect access detected" error.

Is what I'm tasked to do even possible? If so, how is the best way to accomplish it? Do I need to write an authentication module and then an activity module? Is there any way to bypass all of Moodle's authentication and simply use the database abstraction *without* editing the core Moodle configuration files? (I know it's possible by modifying the Moodle code, but that is sadly not an option).

I have plenty of PHP experience, but I only have about 4 hours of Moodle experience and I'm getting nowhere fast.

Comment: +1.  Moodle, academia, and "various political reasons" seem to go hand in hand with "getting nowhere fast"

Comment: @Brad - I could have finished this project in under a day had it been run on a normal web server, independently. Unfortunately I am not the one who makes these decisions here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you might be trying to access the script while coming in from a host other than what poodle has specified in its config file. You could try dumping you http_host and noodles wwwroot to see if the line up. I'm less familiar with 2 than 1.9 but you might be able to define abort_after_config then include config then change the cfg wwwroot then define abort_after_config_cancel then include setup. Otherwise you could spoof the host otherwise you can delete the check in Tue lib/setup.pup file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure quite what you are trying to achieve here but any of the following may work.

(1) If you have a stand-alone platform you want delivered within an LMS framework then you might offer a counter proposal of developing it in your preferred environment but wrapping it in [LTI](http://www.imsglobal.org/toolsinteroperability2.cfm). Moodle can then deliver it via the External Tool plugin and you can get two-way communications between the two for authentication and tracking.

(2) Doing it in Moodle

Create an authentication with a [login_hook](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins#loginpage_hook.28.29) and make sure this is is moved to the top of the authentication plugins list so that it is checked first before the others. Use the hook to process the hex key (as GET or POST parameter) or take you to an alternate process and return true (or create session). You could also use the 'alternative login page' in the authentication settings alongside this plugin hook. This should take of authentication.

If enrolment is not an issue then create your plugin as a local plugin (not mod) and use the above hook to redirect to this page after login. This gives you a bit more flexibility in the libraries you use and you can still use front-page enrolments if necessary as a workaround. If you really need enrolments, course roles, and gradebook then use a mod to leverage these. There is a single activity course format in the latest Moodle that gives you a format to run just your bespoke activity on its own.

Finally develop your own layout type in the theme for the local plugin if using that or for the course and incourse layouts if using courses so that you can control what of the  standard Moodle navigation and structure you want.

If the plugin is sharing a Moodle already being used for other activities then you'll need to be sensitive to this. If you're just running your own thing then it will be much easier.

(3) Use [Web Services](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services) to get what you want from Moodle in your own App.